# Why is my document duplicating to multiple document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have 4 subsites on my Sharepoint site for different departments within our company.  One is for the Sales Department, inside of that I have three Document libraries set up for each division within sales. When I upload a document to one of the libraries it duplicates to the other two.  How can I set it so that each library is separate and contains different documents?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have one document library but are using three web parts to represent the same library.

To create a new library for each division go to `Site Contents` -> `Add an app` -> `Document Library`.